# Segmentation Fault when calling free()

Tags: c, unix, pointers, memory-management, free

I'm building some modular function and I'm not getting why I get a segmentation fault after freeing my module.

**My .h file**

```
void StringInit(String *this, char const *s)
{
    this->str = strdup(s);
    printf("%s\n", this->str);
}

void StringDestroy(String *this)
{
    if(this == NULL || this->str == NULL)
        return;
    this->str = NULL;
    free(this);
}

int main()
{
    char          *str;
    String        test;

    str = "hello\n";
    StringInit(&test, str);
    StringDestroy(&test);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `.h` file?? `main()`??

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't recommend calling your variables 'this'. It will confuse C++ people and make it really confusing if you ever convert the code to C++. Call it 'self' instead or something more descriptive.

Comment: @acarlon you're too right! When I saw "free(this)" I made :O face for at least 5 seconds...

Comment: @acarlon Already confused me, haha. The formatter is syntax-highlighting `this`, even SO is fooled!

Comment: @acarlon, I disagree, question is tagged C, it is allowed as variable name in C? then use it

Comment: @AlterMann - you are welcome to use 'this' for your variable names in C, but there are at least three of us here that would find it confusing. It was just a recommendation for readability by peers, I was not saying that it was invalid C. Also a lot of C++ starts out as C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free` should be used to free pointers that have been allocated using `malloc`.  Your `test` string has been allocated on the *stack*.  As Alfe points out:

```
String*  test = (String*)malloc(sizeof(String));
StringInit(test, str);
StringDestroy(test);
```

And as Adriano's answer points out, you've also allocated a new string with `strdup`.  Seems like there are a myriad of issues here!

Comment: Right so.  You could change your code by using `String *testp; testp = (String *) malloc(sizeof String);` and then use `StringInit(testp, str); StringDestroy(testp);`

Comment: You're right he's calling free on stack allocated object but the point IMO he's freeing **wrong object** ("this" instead of "str"). If he just allocate String with malloc() what he gets is to leak because of strdup.

Comment: +1, beat me to it while I was editing to make the code a little more readable. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to call free for `this->str`, not for `this` (because you allocated a new string with `strdup`). Moreover set a member to `NULL` doesn't free it:

```
if (this == NULL || this->str == NULL)
    return;

free(this->str);
this->str = NULL;
```

Everything else in your code works as expected, you can allocate objects on stack (just remember you don't need to free them).